# How can I get my officers out of the training rooms in Trexel 2?

Tags: trexels-2

In Trexels 2 for Android, after my officers go for training in one of the training rooms, and complete the training, their status remains "In <training room>" and I cannot assign them to a mission or send them for additional training. How can I get my officers out of the training room?

Example:

1. I sent my officer for science training at the Computer Core
2. The Computer Core shows my officer and a 15 minute timer
3. The officer finishes training after 15 minutes. The officer's status is now 'in Computer Core'.
4. If I try to start a mission, it shows the officer as 'in Computer Core' and they cannot be assigned to the mission. Nor can they be assigned for additional training.

Does sending an officer for training "lock" them from other useful interaction (additional training, missions, etc) for a period of time or until the next level? Is there some way to get them back to a useful state?